# error of Observable in auth method Angular 8

Tags: angular

i try build a auth method for login using Angular 8, but the vs code show me error...
Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

btw 
This code was sent to me by a friend to implement in his final proyect for the university

auth .ts

```
  private _baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
    private _userData: UserData;
  token: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }
   getUserData(): Observable<UserData> {
        if (this._userData && this._timeCheck(this._userData.timestamp, 5)) {
            return Observable.of(this._userData).pipe(delay(0));
        } else {
            this._userData = null;
        }
        if (!this._userData) {
            let userData$=new Subject<UserData>();
            this.http.get<UserData>(`${this._baseUrl}auth/login`).subscribe(this._buildObserver(userData$));
            return userData$.asObservable();
        }else{
            return Observable.of(new UserData()).pipe(delay(0));
        }
    }

 isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
        if(this.getToken()) {
            let subject = new Subject<boolean>();
            /*this.getUserData().subscribe(
                (userData:UserData)=>subject.next(true),
                error=>subject.next(false),
                ()=>subject.complete());*/
            return Observable.of(true);
        }else{
            return Observable.of(false);
        }
    }
```

[error in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XanZ1.png)

Comment: Inster of `Observable.of(...` use `of(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical mistake in your code. Even if the `getUserData()` function gets an error you will be returning a true value, which is wrong. Instead you should be returning the subject value after the conditional check i.e.

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {

    // Declare subject here
    let subject = new Subject<boolean>();

    // Initialize it as false
    subject.next(false);

    if(this.getToken()) {
        // Set subject value based on getUserData()
    }

    return subject.asObservable();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import it:

for **Angular >= 6.0.0**

uses RxJS 6.0.0 Angular Changelog 6.0.0

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

And use it like: `return of(false)`

Comment: @jimroot Try out and let me know if that solves your issue. ;)

Comment: ty for the all comments people , but the error is fixed because my proyect partner sendme a wrong commit of that method